how to use embed html with ckeditor5
I hope you are doing well. I am working with PHP and using CKEditor without any issues. Everything loads correctly—images, styles, everything—but there are some functionalities missing, including HTML embed, which I need to include. However, this option does not appear in the toolbar :/
It's worth mentioning that I am using WordPress, but I am doing everything with pure PHP (as per the requirements above).
In my header, I am using the CDN:
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/39.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
And in my code, when I use it, I do it like this:
   const editors   = {};
    const uploadUrl = '<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/panelControl/procesos/ck_upload.php';
    const ruta      = 'publicaciones';

    function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin( editor ) {
      editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
        return new MyUploadAdapter( loader, uploadUrl, ruta );
      };
    }

    function createEditor( selector ) {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector);
      if ( element ) {
        ClassicEditor.create(element, {
          toolbar: {
            items: ['heading', '|', 'imageUpload', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'fontFamily',
            'fontSize', 'htmlEmbed', 'link','bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
            shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
          },
          extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ],
        })
        .then( editor => {
          editors[ selector ] = editor;
        } )
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error initializing CKEditor:', error);
        });
      }
    }

It loads everything else, with the exception of: 'underline', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'htmlEmbed'.
The CK Builder available on the page only allows downloading it for React, Angular, or similar, and it works really well, but I can't use the generated JavaScript files either :/
If anyone knows how to solve this, I would really appreciate it.
Best regards,
The main goal is to upload a code snippet provided by Tableau and be able to display it. If I do it without the HTML embed, the code is saved with incorrect characters, like this:
<p>&lt;div class=\'tableauPlaceholder\'
and Id tried to fix it whit this, but it doesn’t work either:
$allowed_html = array(
        'iframe' => array(
          'width' => array(),
          'height' => array(),
          'src' => array(),
          'frameborder' => array(),
          'allow' => array(),
          'allowfullscreen' => array(),
          'url' => array(),
        ),
        'figure' => array(
          'class' => array(),
        ),
        'p' => array(),
        'img' => array(
          'src' => array(),
          'alt' => array(),
          'class' => array(),
          'width' => array(),
          'height' => array(),
          'style' => array(),
          'border' => array(),
        ),
        'strong' => array(),
        'em' => array(),
        'i' => array(),
        'a' => array(
          'href' => array(),
          'title' => array(),
          'target' => array(),
        ),
        'ul' => array(),
        'li' => array(),
        'ol' => array(),
        'br' => array(),
        'h1' => array(),
        'h2' => array(),
        'h3' => array(),
        'h4' => array(),
        'h5' => array(),
        'h6' => array(),
        'span' => array(
          'class' => array(),
          'style' => array(),
        ),
        'div' => array(
          'class' => array(),
          'style' => array(),
          'id' => array(),
          'position' => array(),
        ),
        'noscript' => array(),
        'object' => array(
          'class' => array(),
          'style' => array(),
          'type' => array(),
          'data' => array(),
          'width' => array(),
          'height' => array(),
        ),
        'param' => array(
          'name' => array(),
          'value' => array(),
        ),
        'script' => array(
          'type' => array(),
          'src' => array(),
        ),
      );
    
      $descripcion  = wp_kses($descripcion, $allowed_html);


it seems that yout code is a little bit different than showed in the documentation, try to change your code like the demonstration.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/html-embed.html
Example code:
ClassicEditor.create(element, {
    plugins: [ HtmlEmbed, /* ... */ ],
    toolbar: [ 'htmlEmbed', /* ... */ ],
    htmlEmbed: {
    showPreviews: true,
    sanitizeHtml: ( inputHtml ) => {
        // Strip unsafe elements and attributes, for example:
        // the `<script>` elements and `on*` attributes.
        const outputHtml = sanitize( inputHtml );

        return {
            html: outputHtml,
            // true or false depending on whether the sanitizer stripped anything.
            hasChanged: true
        };
    }
}


I already try to do that, but doesnt work, i got this message error:
HtmlEmbed is not defined.
I made a console.log looking for what pluggins are include it with my cdn, and this is the list:
['Essentials', 'CKFinderUploadAdapter', 'Autoformat', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'BlockQuote', 'CKBox', 'CKFinder', 'CloudServices', 'EasyImage', 'Heading', 'Image', 'ImageCaption', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageUpload', 'Indent', 'Link', 'List', 'MediaEmbed', 'Paragraph', 'PasteFromOffice', 'PictureEditing', 'Table', 'TableToolbar', 'TextTransformation']
so i don´t know how add that plugin

Take a look at this page, it seems that you need to import them when using cdn
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/getting-started/installation/quick-start.html#installing-ckeditor-5-from-cdn
